# specifying aws region while building S3 client using java property file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient() to build AmazonS3Client client in a Java application.

When I run this, it gives following error:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.
```

I want to supply the region via java property file. I referred to many posts but didn't get what I am looking for.

My question is: What is the variable name which I used to specify the region in a Java property file?

I am not looking for environment variable or credential file. Can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your client using builder pattern:-

```
AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("YOUR_REGION_STRING_HERE").build();
```